# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: iproxy exited with code '234'

Tags: xcode, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

one fine day system restarted and i started seeing this error.
appium version : 1.13.0
Xcode version : 10.1
logs
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: iproxy exited with code '234'. Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 16.30 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'M272023Y7G8WN', ip: '192.168.0.16', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_151'